# woocommerece Add to cart button and buy now button on custom product page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I'm trying to set "Add-to-cart" and "Buy Now" buttons in my product page:

- Add-to-cart button: Simply add product in cart
- Buy Now button:Add-to-cart and redirect to checkout page

I've tried this solution found on blogs:

```
 function dj_redirect_checkout( $url ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
        return $checkout_url;
    }
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_redirect', 'dj_redirect_checkout' );
```

After adding the above code, add-to-cart also redirects link to checkout page. How to accomplish this for both buttons in the product page?

Comment: i'm add another one copy of add-to-cart button for buynow button ,both functionality are same, but i'm trying to add onclick page redirect to chechout when user click buy now button  plesase someone help to solve this problem

Answer (score 4):

Finally find a plugin to add buy now button to my product page, it work fine for simple and variable product page

[link for plugin page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-quick-buy/)

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following code:

```
function woo_redirect_to_checkout() {
 global $woocommerce;
 if($_POST['byenowpro'] == 'byenow'){
$checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $checkout_url;
  }
}
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'woo_redirect_to_checkout');
```

HTML example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="byenowpro" name="byenowpro" value="" />
<input type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button secondary" id="byenow" name="byenow" value="Bye Now" onclick="byenowbutton" />
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: hi  kenorb plz you say me how to write ans

Comment: Check: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). At least it needs to have some explanation or introduction text which I've added for you.